# Arrange text under icons

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with a menu i am making, i want it to be something like:

```
<icon>       <icon>       <icon>
Title        Longer        Title 
             Title
```

now i have it like this:

```
           <icon>       
  <icon>   longer   <icon> 
  Title    Title    Title
```

I made the menu using lists like this (Copy from actual code)

```
      <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="#"><img src="images/buton1.png" class="butonmeniu"><h2 class="meniufont" >Info utile</h2></a>   
          </li>
       </ul>
```

and the css styles are like this

```
.meniufont{
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
margin-right:10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight:normal;
color:#434446;
}
.butonmeniu{
display:block;
}
```

Thanks alot, if you have any questions please ask. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding a width to the li? Ex: width: 33.33%; ?

Comment: Just tried it, does not work as intended

Comment: the code you provided seems to be missing parts... can you create a jsfiddle? after the explanation it seems like a display inline block problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/LpeLnw1c/ there you go

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `li` are using `display:inline-block`

Add `vertical-align:top` to the `li` as the default there is `baseline`.

```css
.meniufont {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: normal;
  color: #434446;
}
.butonmeniu {
  display: block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/20/20" class="butonmeniu">
        <h2 class="meniufont">Title</h2>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/20/20">
        <h2 class="meniufont textjos">Longer <br>Title</h2>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/20/20">
        <h2 class="meniufont">Title</h2>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: i don't know why it's not working on my local host, i will try figure it out, thank you!

Comment: working now, my style was not saving i don't know why but i fixed it. Thanks alot!

Comment: Also, how can i make the icon text from all icons to be aligned at the same height?

Answer (score 1):

```css
li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
      <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="#"><img src="http://placephant.com/80/80" class="butonmeniu"><h2 class="meniufont" >Info utile</h2></a>   
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#"><img src="http://placephant.com/80/80" class="butonmeniu"><h2 class="meniufont" >Info utile Into utile</h2></a>   
          </li>
       </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sup!

I toyed around with what I thought you were trying to achieve.

See this pen : [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/jay_tee/pen/dMKmVg)

```css
#nav { list-style : none;}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; /* Make it whatever you want */
}
.meniufont{
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
margin-right:10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight:normal;
color:#434446;
}
.butonmeniu{
display:block;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <ul id="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="butonmeniu"><h2 class="meniufont" >Info utile</h2>
        </a>   
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="butonmeniu"><h2 class="meniufont" >Info utile</h2>
        </a>   
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="butonmeniu"><h2 class="meniufont" >Info utile</h2>
        </a>   
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: This does not look how the OP requires. Did you see the actual problem in the question?

Comment: I did see what the OP required - I just happened to use images instead of icons.

Comment: No...the issue is the text etc...he provided example layouts.

Comment: I had no example to work off ... but thank you for your input

Comment: It's in the question.

Comment: Well thank you, sir. Next time I'll be sure to try not be so helpful ... I had no idea the code/help police were out.